# How can I write the query showing the first half of the data in ORACLE SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose we have a table. For this table how can I write the query showing the first half of the data in ORACLE SQL?

Example table is below:

| Jobs | Salary |
| --- | --- |
| A | 15000 |
| B | 12500 |

I want to get the following table (half of the table above) as a result of the query.

| Jobs | Salary |
| --- | --- |
| A | 15000 |

Comment: There is no such thing as "the first half" of a table.  Tables represent *unordered* (multi)sets.  Sample data and desired results might clarify your question.

Comment: How do you define "first" or "half"? Based on what value(s) of which column(s), in which order?

Comment: For example, we have a table with four rows. I want to query only the first two rows of this table.

Comment: " I want to query only the first two rows"    As previously stated by @GordonLinoff, there is no such thing as "first" until you supply some ordering rule, via an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

If the DB version is `12c+`, then `ORDER BY` followed by `FETCH` clause might be used such as

```
SELECT *
  FROM job_list  
 ORDER BY Salary DESC
 FETCH FIRST 50 PERCENT ROWS ONLY
```

presuming you need the descendingly ordered salaries. But, you should notice that query returns ***half*** of ***(total number of rows + 1) / 2*** whenever the table has odd-numbered rows of data. Btw, if also *ties* (*equal salary values*) should be included within the first half for the ordered fetched rows, then replace `ONLY` keyword with `WITH TIES`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=167442f39d266d53df3eae5f02b2bfa8)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Though I really don't see any reason why someone would need that, here how I'd solve it

```
select jobs, salary
  from (select jobs, salary, count(1) over() cnt
          from some_table)
 where rownum <= cnt/2; -- this condition is to cut the half of result entries
```

Perhaps you might need to sort it first using an "order by" clause within the subquery

Comment: "Perhaps you might need to sort it first using an "order by" clause"  No "perhaps" to it.  The OP said he wants the "first half".  There is no concept of "first" until you ORDER the set.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want half of your result you can use below query to get only even number of rows:

```
with cte (jobs,salary,rn) as (
select jobs,salary, row_number()over(order by userid)  from table  )
select jobs,salary from cte where mod(rn,2)=0
```